# Using same parsing format for output format

Tags: javascript, formatting, momentjs

With libary [moment](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/special-formats/)  there is option to bring a array of formating options and `momentjs` use the best match for parsing the input.

For Example:

```
var date = moment("29-06-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MM", "DD-MM-YYYY"]);
```

but what if I want the take the same format that using in parsing for output formating.

```
var dateText = date.format('selected parse')
```

How do I know which format `moment` choose to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no exposed function for getting the chosen format, however there is a "private" field named `_f` that contains this information.

```
var m = moment("29-06-1995", ["MM-DD-YYYY", "DD-MM", "DD-MM-YYYY"]);
m._f  // "DD-MM-YYYY"
```

If you use this, be careful when updating versions of moment.  Private fields are not guaranteed to be maintained, and could break between versions.

I've [logged this as a feature request](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/2441) for future moment.js functionality.